# Get all users and profile fields in 1 database call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership, asp.net-authentication

We currently have a page on our website that gets all our users and lists them.

```
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

This page then makes a Profile call for each user as it loops through them in the view.

```
foreach (MembershipUser user in Model)
{
    ProfileBase pb = ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName, true);
    //display fields
}
```

This makes the page load very slowly and is getting worse as we add more users.  At over 4000 now the page can take a minute or 2 to load.  Luckily it's just an admin page, but I'd still like to make it more efficient.

Is there an efficient way I can do all of this in 1 call to the database?

Comment: What is the purpose of `ProfileBase pb = ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName, true);` calling this in the view?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be in the view, that's just how it was implemented inside the display loop.  The view needs to show the profile fields.  Where it happens doesn't matter, as its the individual calls to Profile that are slowing everything down.  I was hoping for a way to make 1 call without having to use a typical join and decode the profile data myself.  It's stored in an inconvenient way in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just recoding the entire site not to use ProfileBase.  I really can't recommend anyone ever implement it.